# Weird behavior when I'm alternating between showing and hiding Flot graphs

Tags: javascript, css, flot

When I hide and display the graphs on the click of a button, the second and third graphs rendered seem to go beyond their CSS boundaries. Like so:

The first graph rendered normally:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/r60eSLx.png]

And the next image after a click of the nav button:
[image: And the next image in line]

The Ids are different in name (to describe different plots for each div of course), but are identical in positioning, as shown in the relevant CSS below.

Relevant CSS:

```
#placeholder_one{
    margin-top:70px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:80%;
    height:350px;
    position:relative;
}
#placeholder_two{
    margin-top:70px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:80%;
    height:350px;
    position:relative;
    display:none;
}
#placeholder_three{
    margin-top:70px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:80%;
    height:350px;
    position:relative;
    display:none;
}
```

The HTML:

```
    <div class="basic_form">
        <span id="title">
                Spectra
        </span> 

        <div id="placeholder_one"></div> 
        <div id="placeholder_two"></div> 
        <div id="placeholder_three"></div> 

        <a href= "#" onclick="move('fwd');"><i id="nav_next" class="icon-double-angle-right about_nav"></i></a>
        <a href= "#" onclick="move('rev');"><i id="nav_rev" class="icon-double-angle-left about_nav"></i></a>
    </div>
```

And finally for reference, the Javascript. The first is simply a navigation structure, the second script is where the plotting actually occurs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentCount = 1;

    function safeCount(op){
        if (op == "add"){
            if (currentCount>=3){
                ;
            }
            else{
                currentCount = currentCount+1;
            }
        }
        if (op == "sub"){
            if (currentCount<=1){
                ;
            }
            else{
                currentCount = currentCount-1;
            }
        }
    }

    function divSelector(count){
         if (count == 1){
                    $('#placeholder_one').fadeIn(1000);
                    $('#placeholder_two').hide();
                    $('#placeholder_three').hide();
                }else if (count == 2){
                    $('#placeholder_one').hide();
                    $('#placeholder_two').fadeIn(1000);
                    $('#placeholder_three').hide();
                }else if (count == 3){
                    $('#placeholder_one').hide();
                    $('#placeholder_two').hide();
                    $('#placeholder_three').fadeIn(1000);
                    }
        else{
            console.log("Count is nothing.");
        }
    }


    //Navigating: pass in "fwd" or "rev"
    function move(direction){    
        if (direction == "fwd"){
            safeCount("add");
            divSelector(currentCount);
        }
        else if (direction =="rev"){
            safeCount("sub");
            divSelector(currentCount);
        }
        else{
            ;
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    function plotList(string_id, data_list){
        $.plot(string_id, [{data:data_list,
                            lines: { show: true },
                            points: { show: false },
                            }],
                            {
                            xaxes: [{position:'bottom',axisLabel:'T(s)'}],
                            yaxes: [{position:'left',axisLabel:'Proper Acceleration (g)'}],
                            grid:{hoverable:true,color:'white',clickable:true}
                            });
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    var test_one = [[0,0],[4,3]];var test_two = [[0,0],[4,3]];var test_three = [[0,0],[4,3]];
    plotList("#placeholder_one",test_one);
    plotList("#placeholder_two",test_two);
    plotList("#placeholder_three",test_three);
    });
});


</script>
```

Any input as to how I could go about rectifying this would be immensely appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flot has issues with plotting graphs in containers that are set to `display:none`.  So, you can either delay calling `$.plot` until the container is visible, or you can use negative margins to have it be off screen,plot, and then have your `divSelector` move them on/off screen.

If you just delay the plots until `divSelector` wants to show them, you'll have something like this:

```
  function divSelector(count) {
      if (count == 1) {
          $('#placeholder_one').fadeIn(1000);
          $('#placeholder_two').hide();
          $('#placeholder_three').hide();
      } else if (count == 2) {
          $('#placeholder_one').hide();
          $('#placeholder_two').show();
          if ($('#placeholder_two').find('canvas').length == 0) {
              plotList("#placeholder_two", test_two);
          }
          $('#placeholder_three').hide();
      } else if (count == 3) {
          $('#placeholder_one').hide();
          $('#placeholder_two').hide();
          $('#placeholder_three').show();

          if ($('#placeholder_three').find('canvas').length == 0) {
              plotList("#placeholder_three", test_three);
          }
      } else {
          console.log("Count is nothing.");
      }
  }
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/Q7T4y

If you'd prefer to keep your fades and what not, you can use the margin thing to build the plot off screen like this:

```
  plotList("#placeholder_one", test_one);
  $('#placeholder_two,#placeholder_three').css({
      'margin-left': '-1000px',
      display: 'block'
  });
  plotList("#placeholder_two", test_two);
  plotList("#placeholder_three", test_three);
  $('#placeholder_two,#placeholder_three').css({
      'margin-left': 'auto',
      display: 'none'
  });
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/Q7T4y/1/